# Need clarification in Django mail sending scenario

Tags: django, email, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I build a mail sending function in django.I did it by referring django [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/email/) .

In doc to specify a email backend,need to add this line in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

settings.py for email

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'anjunair@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'quartentine@name.com'
```

Mail is sending to the email if the `EMAIL_BACKEND` removed from settings.Need some clarification about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs don't tell you to do that. That `console` email backend is specifically to NOT use SMTP - it outputs directly to the console.

Remove it, and keep it that way if you want to send via smtp (gmail).